# Create an anonymous type object from an arbitrary text file

Tags: c#, dictionary, text-files, anonymous-types

I need a sensible way to draw arbitrary text files into a C# program, and produce an arbitrary anonymous type object, or perhaps a composite dictionary of some sort.

I have a representative text file that looks like this:

```
adapter 1: LPe11002
  Factory IEEE: 10000000 C97A83FC
  Non-Volatile WWPN: 10000000 C93D6A8A , WWNN: 20000000 C93D6A8A
adapter 2: LPe11002
  Factory IEEE: 10000000 C97A83FD
  Non-Volatile WWPN: 10000000 C93D6A8B , WWNN: 20000000 C93D6A8B
```

Is there a way to get this information into an anonymous type object or some similar structure?

The final anonymous type might look something like this, if it were composed in C# by hand:

```
new
{
    adapter1 = new 
    { 
        FactoryIEEE = "10000000 C97A83FC",
        Non-VolatileWWPN = "10000000 C93D6A8A",
        WWNN = "20000000 C93D6A8A"
    }
    adapter2 = new 
    { 
        FactoryIEEE = "10000000 C97A83FD",
        Non-VolatileWWPN = "10000000 C93D6A8B",
        WWNN = "20000000 C93D6A8B"
    }
}
```

Note that, as the text file's content is arbitrary (i.e. the keys could be *anything*), a specialized solution (e.g. that looks for names like "FactoryIEEE") won't work. However, the structure of the file will always be the same (i.e. indentation for groups, colons and commas as delimiters, etc).

Or maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, and you have a better idea?

Comment: Why do you want to use anonymous types for this? Why not dynamic types?

Comment: I hadn't thought of dynamic types.  It's a good idea, but unfortunately Mono is the target platform, so dynamic typing is not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. Your "anonymous type object" data is hard to *construct* and hard to *use*. To construct it, you'd have to use reflection trickery. And for what?

Consider a PrintReport function. This function would not get any simpler because of the ATO usage. Far from it, it'd get more complicated and slow, having to use reflection itself to iterate over the keys. Your solution *might* have made sense if there was a small, fixed number of possible keys. Then usage syntax such as "obj.FactoryIEEE" might have been preferred.

The way I'd go about this is with a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, or, say a `List<AdapterRecord>` where AdapterRecord is

```
class AdapterRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out this 2-part article. It parses XML files in a fluent way. It can be adapted to parse your text files I think.

- [Fluent XML Parsing Using C#'s Dynamic Type Part 1](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-1)
- [Fluent XML Parsing Using C#'s Dynamic Type Part 2](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/kevin-hazzard/fluent-xml-parsing-using-cs-dynamic-type-part-2)

It uses C# 4 dynamic typing to do what you want.

Comment: +1, it's technically correct but I hope I never run into this.

Comment: Very nice.  I'm sure I'll use something like this eventually.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that C# 4.0 is not an available option.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's no way to do this even in C# 4.

Besides, thinking about it if you don't know what the keys will be then any sort of strongly typed access would be tough, and a simple split + insertion into dictionary/list/etc. would make more sense.

Comment: Yeah you can do it with c# dynamic typing.

Comment: I checked though. You can't access an ExpandoObject via index, so there's no way to programmatically set values on an object where you don't know the variable name till execution time.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't love them, perhaps a `DataTable` would serve...